# Cakephp model find multiple 'not like'

Tags: php, orm, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

A VARCHAR field in my db has a comma separated list of tags.

I have a list of values that I want to exclude, but having trouble.

This is what I was trying...

```
$result = $this->Tags->find(
  'all',
  'conditions'=>array(
      'fieldName NOT LIKE'=>'%tag1%',
      'fieldName NOT LIKE'=>'%tag2%'
  )
);
```

That works on the first line in the condition only.

Have also tried...

```
$result = $this->Tags->find(
  'all',
  'conditions'=>array(
      'NOT'=>array(
          'fieldName LIKE'=>'%tag1%',
          'fieldName LIKE'=>'%tag2%'
      (
  )
);
```

I keep looking in the Cake documentation, but haven't been able to find this specifically. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues here. First of all, the syntax is incorrect. I assume that this is just a mistake you made typing your question.

The second issue is harder to detect. If you include in the array the key

```
'fieldName NOT LIKE'
```

more than once, it will overwrite itself.

To prevent this, you have to wrap it in an array:

```
$result = $this->Tags->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        array('fieldName NOT LIKE'=>'%tag1%'),
        array('fieldName NOT LIKE'=>'%tag2%')
)));
```

Another option is to write the query as follows:

```
$result = $this->Tags->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'fieldName NOT REGEXP'=>'tag1|tag2',
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

i look your syntax is not true,
maybe you forget array after 'all',

like this,

```
$result = $this->Tags->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=> array( 'fieldName NOT LIKE' =>'%tag1%',
    'fieldName NOT LIKE'=>'%tag2%')
 ));
```